# Do Boss battles have a hidden time limit?

Tags: bravely-default

I don't remember exactly what boss battles did which to me, but I have noticed that several boss battles gave me pg at the end while others did not.

As far as I can tell most of the boss battles that did not give pg, I took a bit longer than I would have liked.

Does anybody know if some boss battles just never give pg or if there is a turn limit where you will no longer receive pg as a reward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My experience so far has led me to believe that some bosses just don't offer PG rewards. In later chapters,

> when you can fight sub-mission bosses again (two times so far for all of them),

I've noticed quite a few of the bosses, possibly all, give 0 PG and EXP but 999 JP.

The amount of turns went down drastically between the fights so I don't believe that there is a turn limit.

Edit:

[Here's a spread sheet I've put together showing all of the boss rewards (PG, EXP, JP, Items and Steal-able Items) using GameFAQs a GameFAQ walk through as my source. If you find anything wrong or missing, feel free to let me know.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AlRCT0KqRByMdHJwVUc4RmVTT2IzamdXSE1JSWpsLVE&usp=sharing)

[GameFAQs source](http://www.gamefaqs.com/3ds/729328-bravely-default/faqs/68431)

Comment: If you can make a list of the bosses that give PG or be sure that none of them gives it (source), would be great.

Comment: Sure, since I can't seem to find a good list of boss PG, EXP, JP rewards I may start recording that information as I beat them. Unfortunatly, I am half way through chapter 6 so it'll be incomplete data until I start another playthrough.

Answer (score 1):

The battles do not have a time limit.  Ignoring bonuses which are shown separately, the xp, pg, and JP you get is always the same.